# Polling from gmail activated domains

Tags: gmail

I m trying to poll email from an email address like "abc@falconamg.com", this falconamg.com service is provided by gmail only. If i give "pop.gmail.com" as pop servername it's saying "authentication failed". Now where do I find the pop3 servername & other account settings for this email account "abc@falconamg.com". (UserName & Password is correct able to login through browser, SSL also supported.)

Note: From the same machine i m able to poll emails from gmail account through my program.

Thanks

Comment: When you say "service is provided by gmail only", does that mean you are using Google Apps for Domains? That is the only way I know of to use "gmail" with domains other than gmail.com.

Answer (score 2):

From http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=13287

Make sure your port number is correct too.

```
Incoming Mail (POP3) Server - requires SSL:     pop.gmail.com
Use SSL:                                        Yes
Port:                                           995
Outgoing Mail (SMTP) Server - requires TLS:     smtp.gmail.com (use authentication)
Use Authentication:                             Yes
Use STARTTLS:                                   Yes (some clients call this SSL)
Port:                                           465 or 587
Account Name:    your full email address (including @gmail.com or @your_domain.com)
Email Address:   your email address (username@gmail.com or username@your_domain.com)
Password:        your Gmail password
```

Answer (score 1):

Is POP enabled for that address? Go into the GMail settings panel, select "Forwarding and POP/IMAP" and make sure "Enable POP for all mail (even mail that's already been downloaded)" is selected.

Answer (score 1):

Google POP3 server is pop.gmail.com, you must use SSL and port 995. You can find Gmail's server settings [here](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=13287).

Comment: Thx for ur reply...
I m using the same settings that is mentioned in the link. But am getting authentication failed error for "abc@falconamg.com". 

But am able to poll emails from an account like "abc@gmail.com" from the same machine. 

when i change from "abc@gmail.com" to "abc@falconamg.com" which is gmail activated account. it's failing.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are [enabling POP Download capability](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=13273) in your Google Apps for Domains account and saving the changes.

You may have to wait 10 - 15 minutes for that to take effect.